# Using a particular image to justify a (specific) trig integral equality.

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

I would like to include the following string of equalities in a paper:
$$\sin ^2(x) + \cos ^2(x) = 1$$

$$\int _0^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^2 (x)dx + \int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \cos ^2 (x)dx = \int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} 1 \cdot dx $$
$$2 \cdot \int_0 ^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2(x)dx = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\int_0 ^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2(x)dx = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$$

And I would like to justify the **third** equality using the following image:
[image]

The first equality shows us that the sum of the functions $f(x) = \sin ^2(x), g(x) = \cos ^2(x)$ is one.

> How can we conclude that they have *equal areas* though? Do we use the fact that they are cofunctions?

I'm sure this is simple, but I keep going in circles here (pun intended, if you like).

Comment: $\sin (x) = \cos (\frac{\pi}{2} - x)$ has *got* to be the answer, I'm just struggling with the language. Is it in terms of reflection symmetry?

Comment: Note that $\cos x = \sin(\pi/2-x)$ and rotate your figure by a half-turn about its center.

Comment: Thanks, @Blue. I was going down that path! Care to put something to that effect in an answer so I can accept it? p.s. email me sometime about the games :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. Co-functionality is the key.

Simply note that $\cos x = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$ and observe that this gives you half-turn rotational symmetry about the center of your figure.